# In Ruby I need to split a sentence into sub-sentences

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

Given the string:

```
"See Spot Run"
```

I need to return an array with:

```
[ "See", "Spot", "run", "See Spot", "Spot run", "See Spot Run" ]
```

So far I have:

```
term = "The cat sat on the mat"
#=> "The cat sat on the mat" 

arr = term.split(" ")
#=> ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"] 

arr.length.times.map { |i| (arr.length - i).times.map { |j| arr[j..j+i].join(" ") } }.flatten(1)
#=> ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat", "The cat", "cat sat", "sat on", "on the", "the mat", "The cat sat", "cat sat on", "sat on the", "on the mat", "The cat sat on", "cat sat on the", "sat on the mat", "The cat sat on the", "cat sat on the mat", "The cat sat on the mat"]
```

This is going to happen a lot of times, so can you think of a way to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) in a loop: (although it's not any faster)

```
arr = %w[The cat sat on the mat]
(1..arr.size).flat_map { |i| arr.each_cons(i).map { |words| words.join(' ') } }
#=> ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat",
#    "The cat", "cat sat", "sat on", "on the", "the mat",
#    "The cat sat", "cat sat on", "sat on the", "on the mat",
#    "The cat sat on", "cat sat on the", "sat on the mat",
#    "The cat sat on the", "cat sat on the mat",
#    "The cat sat on the mat"]
```

Comment: ```each_cons```! Man, I must have looked over that doc page about five times trying to find that method and I totally missed it. You're some kind of hero!

Comment: Unfortunately benchmark shows no speed increase. Odd, as the method is implemented in C. Still, at least I'm using the proper Ruby methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this, may be not as elegant as other answer.

```
str = "The cat sat on the mat"
words = str.split
puts words.flat_map.with_index { |i, idx| 
    words.
        repeated_combination(idx + 1).
        select{ |*x| str[x.join(' ')]}.
        collect {|x| x.join(' ') }
}
```

Output

```
The
cat
sat
on
the
mat
The cat
cat sat
sat on
on the
the mat
The cat sat
cat sat on
sat on the
on the mat
The cat sat on
cat sat on the
sat on the mat
The cat sat on the
cat sat on the mat
The cat sat on the mat
```